# How to write a code for Jquery Ajax in laravel?

Tags: jquery, laravel

In my blade file, I have **3 div's**, with 3 **different ID's**.

```
<div id ="id1">0</div>
<div id ="id2">0</div>
<div id ="id3">0</div>
```

The `0` in each div could be replaced by `Time()` For ex, which gives the result as `1666111`.

**If the Routes/web.php looks like this**

```
Route::get('/getTime/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\TimeController@getTime');
```

How to use JQuery Ajax to fetch the `time()` in the controller and to bind the value to each **div's**.

Could some one please help?
Thanks

Comment: Does this time must be updated in interval or one time display?

Comment: Why make an ajax request when you can get the same `time()` value in javascript with `Math.floor(Date.now()/1000)` ?

Comment: I need to display the time() for 3 different div's, when I visit the URL with 3 different Id's  as `http://www.project.test/getTime/id1` It should display the  same/different time for each div's, So I need AJAX to get the request. @IGP

Comment: @Justinas, the time() should be different/same for the each div's, When I pass the URL as `http://www.project.test/getTime/id1`, It should display the `time()` for each div's respectively.

Comment: And when will you pass the url? After clicking on a button?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass the ids to the route. `time()` expects no parameters.

```
Route::get('/getTime', 'App\Http\Controllers\TimeController@getTime');
```

```
public function getTime()
{
    return time();    
}
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/getTime'
        method: 'get'
    })
    .done(time => {
        $('#id1').text(time);
        $('#id2').text(time);
        $('#id3').text(time);
    });
});
```

---

But this is a really convoluted way to get the unix timestamp on the divs. You could just do it like this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    const unixTimestamp = Math.floor(Date.now()/1000);
    $('#id1').text(unixTimestamp);
    $('#id2').text(unixTimestamp);
    $('#id3').text(unixTimestamp);
});
```